# Earth-Sun distance equation

Tags: geometry, physics

I was studying solar geometry and I read the next equation

$$r=r_{0}\left(1+0,017\sin\left[\frac{2\pi(d_{n}-93)}{365}\right]\right) $$

where $r_{0}$ is the average distance between the Earth and the Sun and 0.017 is the eccentricity of the earth orbit, $d_{n}$ is the days.

My question is how to proof the equation and why the argument of the sine.
I suppose that is for properties of the ellipse (the orbit of the Earth is a ellipse) but doesn't work.

Comment: What does the equation describe?  The distance between the Sun and the Earth?

Comment: Neal: Yes, DonAntonio: excuse me but you could explain more about that please

Comment: What's $d_n$ here?

Comment: days, for example dn=1 is the 1 january

Comment: @kEoz http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: [Kepler's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation) can be derived from Newton's laws, but it will not fit easily into this kind of space.  It is derived in any upper division classical mechanics text.

Answer (score 1):

The distance as a function of the angle from perihelion is
$$
r=\frac{a\left(1-e^2\right)}{1+e\cos(\theta)}
$$
where $a$ is the semi-major axis, $e$ is the eccentricity of the orbit, and $\theta$ is the angle from perihelion.

The relation of $\theta$ to $t$, the time since perihelion passage, is
$$
\frac{2\pi t}{P}=\phi-e\sin(\phi)
$$
and
$$
\tan\left(\frac\theta2\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+e}{1-e}}\tan\left(\frac\phi2\right)
$$
where $P$ is the period of revolution ($\phi$ is called the eccentric anomaly).

These formulas are derived in [planets.pdf](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/pdf/planets.pdf) and [kepler.pdf](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/pdf/kepler.pdf).

---

The formula cited in the question is a first-order [deferent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferent_and_epicycle) approximation assuming that [the anomalistic year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year#Sidereal.2C_tropical.2C_and_anomalistic_years) is 365 days and the earth passes perihelion when $d_n=1.75$.